# Where to highlight UICollectionViewCell: delegate or cell?

Tags: ios, ios6, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

According to the [Collection View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCellsandViews/CreatingCellsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH7-SW8) one should handle the visual state of the cell highlights in the `UICollectionViewDelegate`. Like this:

```
- (void)collectionView:(PSUICollectionView *)collectionView didHighlightItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MYCollectionViewCell *cell = (MYCollectionViewCell*)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell highlight];
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didUnhighlightItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MYCollectionViewCell *cell = (MYCollectionViewCell*)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell unhighlight];
}
```

What I don't like about this approach is that it adds logic to the delegate that is very specific to the cell. In fact, `UICollectionViewCell` manages its highlighted state independently, via the `highlighted` property.

Wouldn't overriding `setHighlighted:` be a cleaner solution, then?

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted
{
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted];
    if (highlighted) {
        [self highlight];
    } else {
        [self unhighlight];
    }
}
```

Are there any disadvantages to this approach instead of the delegate approach?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

As the documentation says, you can rely on `highlighted` property to be changed while the cell is highlighted. For example the following code will make the cell red when highlighted (not its subviews though):

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted {
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [super drawRect:rect];

    if (self.highlighted) {
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1, 0, 0, 1);
        CGContextFillRect(context, self.bounds);
    } 
}
```

And if you **add** something like this the background will become purple (red + opaque blue):

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)colView didHighlightItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [colView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:1 alpha:0.5];
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)colView didUnhighlightItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [colView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = nil;
}
```

So you can use both together (not necessarily both changing the cell appearance). The difference is that with delegate methods you also have `indexPath`. It might be used to create multi-selection (you will use this methods together with selection delegate methods), to show some preview while the cell is highlighted, to show some animation with other views... There's quite a few appliance for this delegate methods in my opinion.

As a conclusion, I would leave the cell appearance to be handled by the cell itself and use delegate methods to let controller make something cool in the same time.

Comment: +1 Thanks. I like the `setNeedsDisplay` + `drawRect` approach. Maybe I would check if `self.highlighted != highlighted` (on line 1) before calling `setNeedsDisplay`, to avoid unnecessary drawing.

Comment: You don't need the ```drawRect``` and ```setNeedsDisplay``` calls when overriding ```setHighlighted:```. This will do: ```self.contentView.backgroundColor = highlighted ? UIColor(white: 217.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0) : nil```

Comment: @bizz84 if you read the answer carefully that is explained there.

Comment: beautiful explanation I was searching for this to be clarified!

Answer (score 17):

Two possible approaches are outlined below.

**Cell Subclassing**

Cleaner approach if already subclassing from `UICollectionViewCell`.

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    override var highlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            self.contentView.backgroundColor = highlighted ? UIColor(white: 217.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0) : nil
        }
    }
}
```

**UICollectionViewDelegate**

Less clean, requires the collection view delegate to know about the presentation logic of the cells.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didHighlightItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 217.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0) // Apple default cell highlight color
    }
}


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didUnhighlightItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: The first solution is awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

It is enough for highlighting cell (Swift 4)

```
class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
...
    override var isHighlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            if isHighlighted {
                self.contentView.alpha = 0.6
            }
            else {
                self.contentView.alpha = 1.0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Notice that `UICollectionViewCell` has a `selectedBackgroundView` property. By default, it's nil. Just create a view for this property, and it will appear when the user touches the cell.

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    let view = UIView(frame: contentView.bounds)
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.94, alpha: 1.0)
    selectedBackgroundView = view
}
```

Comment: Very clean implementation which avoids the `delaysContentTouches` problems.

Comment: This flickers on multiple cells in iOS 13 when coming back from detail screen :/...

Comment: Never mind, I was calling `collectionView.reloadData()` in `viewDidAppear` ‍♂️

Answer (score 6):

Well...as all of these methods are correct. I've found the way that seems like the easiest one to me. Just override the setSelected: method (for example to change background color):

```
-(void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected{
    self.backgroundColor = selected?[UIColor greenColor]:[UIColor grayColor];
    [super setSelected:selected];
}
```

...it works "out of the box" (even with collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection)

Comment: If you have multiple cells and you scroll up and down, it selects random cells, is there a solution for that?

Answer (score 2):

As taken directly from UICollectionViewCell.h - overriding both `setSelected` and `setHighlighted` are correct.  Depending upon your situation you might consider assigning custom views to `backgroundView` and `selectedBackgroundView` which are swapped automatically on selection.

```
// Cells become highlighted when the user touches them.
// The selected state is toggled when the user lifts up from a highlighted cell.
// Override these methods to provide custom UI for a selected or highlighted state.
// The collection view may call the setters inside an animation block.
@property (nonatomic, getter=isSelected) BOOL selected;
@property (nonatomic, getter=isHighlighted) BOOL highlighted;

// The background view is a subview behind all other views.
// If selectedBackgroundView is different than backgroundView, it will be placed above the background view and animated in on selection.
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *backgroundView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *selectedBackgroundView;
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3:   (based on the answer of A-Live)

```
import UIKit

class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    override var highlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        super.drawRect(rect)
        myImageView.highlighted = self.highlighted
    }
}
```

Swift 4

```
import UIKit

class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    override var isHighlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        myImageView.isHighlighted = self.isHighlighted
    }
}
```

Comment: setNeedsDisplay is not needed, draw rect is not needed.  Just move your logic from the draw rect to the didSet.