# UILongPressGestureRecognizer on collection view breaks cell highlighting

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uigesturerecognizer

When I add a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` on my collectionView (I'm doing it  like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18848725/long-press-gesture-on-uicollectionviewcell)), the collection view stops highlighting cells as expected.

I'm handling the cell highlighting in my UICollectionViewCellSubclass, like it's explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15483229/where-to-highlight-uicollectionviewcell-delegate-or-cell):

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];

    if (self.highlighted) {
        //Here I show my highlighting layer
    }
    else {
        //Here I hide my highlighting layer   
    }
}

- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted
{
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted];
    [self setNeedsDisplay]; //This call draw rect and show/hide the highlighting layer
}
```

The problem seems to be that, when I add the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` gesture on the collection view, drawRect is not being called after setting highlighted to YES.

If I move the logic to show my highlighting layer in `setHighlighted:YES`, I can't see the touching-feedback because `setHighlighted:NO` its being called immediately after! (This happens only after adding the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`).

I've also tried to move the logic in `touchesBegan`/`touchesEnded` but then `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it looks like the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` is blocking the touches required for the UICollectionView to highlight the cell. It doesn't look like there is a good way to forward the touches, so I'd imagine you will have to handle the highlighting manually if you want that to appear. You could do it through a separate method than setHighlighted, or try to use the cell.highlighted property to do your drawing.

Here is an example I came up with that worked for my UICollectionView

```
-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
//    if (gestureRecognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
//        return;
//    }
    CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.collectionView];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:p];
    if (indexPath == nil){
        NSLog(@"couldn't find index path");
    } else {
        // get the cell at indexPath (the one you long pressed)
        UICollectionViewCell* cell = [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (gestureRecognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
            if (!cell.highlighted) {
                [cell setHighlighted:YES];
            }
            return;
        }
        [cell setHighlighted:NO];
        // do stuff with the cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I've already done something like that, but this is working only for longPressing and not for tapping. If I put also a UITapGestureRecognizer on my collectionView, then didSelectRowAtIndexPath doesn't work anymore...

Comment: You can call [self.collectionView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]  from the UITapGestureRecognizer selector, as well as doing the highlighting you want