# UiCollectionview allow single selection for specific cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

In Collection view i am select the one cell but it is selected multiple cells.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView      *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
CustomCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.Selectitems.tag=indexPath.row;
[cell.Selectitems addTarget:self action:@selector(selectitem:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
-(void)selectitem :(UIButton *)sender{
if ([sender isSelected]) {
    [sender setSelected: NO];
    cell.check = YES;
     [cell.Selectitems setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"product-uncheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}else{
        [sender setSelected: YES];
        cell.check = YES;
      [cell.Selectitems setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"product-check.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
}
```

Check bellow my image link
    [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIgDH.png

Comment: can you add some more code

Comment: Under selectitem button i am select the one cell but it is selected down cell also.

Comment: I understand, for your code we can't find the issue

Comment: if ([sender isSelected]) {
        [sender setSelected: NO];
        cell.check = YES;
            
        [cell.Selectitems setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"product-uncheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
             } else{
            [sender setSelected: YES];
            cell.check = YES;
            self.selectedIndexPath=indexPath;
            
            [cell.Selectitems setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"product-check.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];}

Comment: good same thing do in cellForItemAtIndexPath also

Comment: How to add,Please post the answer

Comment: Check this answer Its easy. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15483229/where-to-highlight-uicollectionviewcell-delegate-or-cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the complete code which may satisfy your requirement for checkbox with `collectionview`

https://www.dropbox.com/s/e43zk55surlwjlk/CollectionCkeck.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

When you clicked on second cell you are not changing image on first cell.

So make sure that if you clicked on any cell change the image as `product-check.png` and previous cell image as `product-uncheck.png`

Answer (score 0):

Do like this When Button is Pressed

```
-(void)selectitem :(UIButton *)sender{

//Get Index path from Button Tag
  NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0];

// get Cell instance and than do whatever you want with Cell items
CustomCell *cell = *cell = [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if ([cell.Selectitems isSelected]) {
    [cell.Selectitems setSelected: NO];
    cell.check = YES;
     [cell.Selectitems setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"product-uncheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}else{
        [cell.Selectitems setSelected: YES];
        cell.check = YES;
      [cell.Selectitems setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"product-check.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
}
```

i hope this will solve your problem .

Comment: CustomCell *cell = *cell = [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath]; here Showing this error:Assigning to 'CustomCell' from incompatible type 'UICollectionViewCell * _Nullable'

Comment: CustomCell *cell = [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

sorry for that mistake ,,,, i have written two time "cell"   ... id this gives error  than Cast cell to CustomCell

Comment: thank you for your valuable time spend for me.Already some one the answer.